# Grab an entire Typo3 website as a static site

Tags: typo3

Can I download/grab an entire Typo3 website as a static site to run it without a PHP server and a database? I just want to run this snapshot as a plain HTML site.

Comment: I downloaded the site using wget but it has only index file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For Windows/Linux/Android

I am using the following tool very often to clone static html sites...

http://www.httrack.com/

Comment: well it seems this little tool did me the favor.

Answer (score 2):

wget is a very powerful tool. Important is that you convert the URLs within the site to relative URLs which wget can do on demand (-k).

You can check the result by disabling the network connection and checking if links within the site still work and all assets (e.g. images, JavaScript files etc.) load from your local copy.

This is what I typically use:

```
# -E : change extension, e.g. convert HTML file to .html
# -p : download requisites (e.g. images, JavaScript etc.)
# -nc: no-clobber : do not overwrite
# -m : mirror (means download recursive, etc.)
# -k : convert links to local links
wget -E -p -nc -m -k <url>
```

e.g.

```
wget -E -p -nc -m -k https://example.com
```

- Instead of -m you can also be more specific (-m equals -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing, check the man page).
- Not sure if you need -nc, I don't remember why I used that.
- You definitely need -k (unless you will host the download using the same domain) * and -p to download all asssets.
- -E is more important for local viewing without a webserver, you don't need that if you host the result on a webserver.

The converting of links will be done at the end, so if you check the result while wget is still downloading you will not see the final result.

Comment: Well, also I wrote my own grabber application to export the entire site using Java. Because the site had some custom elements from the developed extensions. Now that application is capable of exporting the entire site including the custom elements as well. Thank you.

Comment: @PHJCJO That sound pretty cool. Perhaps you can make it available as open source. I need this functionality from time to time. For now, the wget solution was sufficient but it still has its flaws.

Answer (score 1):

If you access to a linux system (like ubuntu) you can use the wget commandline tool or "mirror".

```
wget --mirror http://yoursite.com/
```

for other systems like windows there are also several tools like that just try to search for something like "http site mirror" or "http download site" or something.

Comment: I downloaded the site using wget but it has only index file downloaded? no other files...

Comment: wget has one drawback: It is signle threaded. It takes much longer to mirror a site with it. For that reason we, too, switched to Httrack

Comment: You need at least -p to also download the assets, also possibly -k to convert the links.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the TYPO3 extensions nc_staticfilecache which will generate static HTML files of your site.